# Is this c++ double linked list operation valid? Deletion of elements.

Tags: c++

The goal is to do operations with the list ... X1 X2 X3...., specifically delete.

Double linked list

ptr is pointing at X2

```
(ptr->prev)->next = ptr->next;
(ptr->next)->prev = ptr->prev;
delete ptr;
```

Or do I have to declare two new pointers to handle X1 and X3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should work. Declaring two more pointers should not be necessary.